# contribute to vs account for

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference, phrase-usage

Poor transport facilities and lack of resources raw materials and energy also partly _______ the job in contrast fulfillment.

In dictionary, I could find both have similar meanings. I wonder which one is more suitable.

> account for: to be the explanation or cause of something
>
> contribute to: to be one of the causes of something

Comment: Could you explain what the sentence means and possibly provide more context? I’m struggling to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the adverb "partly" is used here, we know that there are other factors affecting the subject.  They are implicitly acknowledged but not stated.  Hence the phrase "contribute to" would be a better choice than "account for".

Using "account for" that would imply that the listed items fully explain the situation.